# I tried to save rtf file with pictures to sql server but I can't retrieve that data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I tried to save rtf file with pictures to sql server but I can't retrieve that data from the table. The error says format is not valid.

This is my rtf file(with an image) saving code to sql

```
//saving code
private void tsbtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    FileStream stream = null;
    string rtf_date = monthCalendar1.SelectionEnd.ToString();
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA");
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(rtf_date); //uses the current Thread's culture
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection cn = null;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = null;
    try
    {
        rtbDocument.SaveFile("temp.rtf");
        stream = new FileStream("temp.rtf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        int size = Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length);
        Byte[] rtf = new Byte[size];
        stream.Read(rtf, 0, size);
        cn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\Desktop\myproject_c#\diary\photogallery\RicherTextBox_src\RicherTextBox\diary.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");
        cn.Open();
        cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO rtf (user_rtf_id,rtf_date,rtf_file_content) VALUES(1,@dt,'@rtf')", cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", dt);
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter paramRTF =
        new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@rtf",
                                  SqlDbType.Image,
                                  rtf.Length,
                                  ParameterDirection.Input,
                                  false,
                                  0, 0, null,
                                  DataRowVersion.Current,
                                  rtf);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramRTF);
        int rowsUpdated = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} rows updated", rowsUpdated));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (null != stream) stream.Close();
        if (null != cmd) cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        if (null != cn) cn.Close();
    }
}
```

This is my c# code for retrieving my saved data from sql.there is the exception "file format not valid"

```
//retrieving code
private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    rtbDocument.Clear();
    SqlConnection cn = null;
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    SqlDataReader reader = null;
    string date = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToString();
    textBox1.Text = date; 

    try
    {
        cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\Desktop\myproject_c#\diary\photogallery\RicherTextBox_src\RicherTextBox\diary.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");
        cn.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT rtf_file_content FROM rtf WHERE rtf_date='4/10/2015' AND user_rtf_id=1", cn);

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        reader.Read();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
            {
                Byte[] rtf = new Byte[Convert.ToInt32((reader.GetBytes(0, 0,
                                                       null, 0, Int32.MaxValue)))];
                long bytesReceived = reader.GetBytes(0, 0, rtf, 0, rtf.Length);
                ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                rtbDocument.Rtf = encoding.GetString(rtf, 0, Convert.ToInt32(bytesReceived));
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (null != reader) reader.Close();
        if (null != cn) cn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a simple mistake with the way you specify the values in your SQL command.

```
INSERT INTO rtf (user_rtf_id,rtf_date,rtf_file_content) VALUES(1,@dt,'@rtf')
```

Notice how you have quotes around the `@rtf` paramter name.

It should be `@rtf` instead of `'@rtf'`.

With your current code, if you look at the data inserted into your database, you would see the value `0x40727466` which is the ASCII encoded value for `@rtf` as a string (like '@', 'r', 't', 'f')

Comment: You welcome. Since it solved your problem, you should mark it as an answer ;)

Comment: i'm new to site.it's my mistake.sorry.